# What is causing this error?

Tags: magento

Trace:

```
#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/wishupon/app/Mage.php(222): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/wishupon/app/Mage.php(476): Mage::register('_singleton/cust...', false)
#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/wishupon/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('customgrid/obse...')
#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/wishupon/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/wishupon/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(528): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#5 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/wishupon/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#6 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/wishupon/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(408): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#7 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/wishupon/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#8 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/wishupon/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/wishupon/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/wishupon/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/wishupon/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

Comment: Can you share more details such as what you did before this happened? Did you install a module or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is cause by a missing file, or an event configured badly, or a model alias not declared properly.
For an event `controller_action_predispatch_....` (I cant see the rest of the event name in the error message - probably `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_login` but not so sure) the observer `customgrid/observer` is called.
Either the class `Namespace_Customgrid_Model_Observer` is missing (The namespace can be anything I just placed `Namespace` as a placeholder) or in the `config.xml` of the extension the model alias is not declared correctly. It should be something like this:

```
<models>
    <customgrid>
        <class>Namespace_Customgrid_Model</class><!-- again `Namespace` is just a placeholder. it can be anything-->
    </customgrid>
</models>
```

Look in your `config.xml` files for the text `customgrid/observer` and post in your question what ever you can find if you cannot figure out the problem. Actually post the full file you find that in.

**Off topic a bit but nice to know:**
The exception is actually thrown because of a Magento small bug in the `getSingleton` method. In Magento singletons are not actually singletons. It's a combination of factory and registry. You cannot have 2 values with the same key in `$_registry`, but when instantiating a model using `getSingleton` instead of checking `array_key_exists($key, self::$_registry)` it is checked `if (!self::registry($registryKey))`. If the first time `getSingleton` was called the value was `false` or `null` (as it happens for you because the model is missing or not declared properly), the second time you get your error.
This bug is not critical. If you fix the errors in your custom module this shouldn't happen.